# Update tileLayer url in react-leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, chakra-ui

So I got this code running to render a leaflet ok, trying to replace the url whenever the colorMode changes is the challenge here.

useEffect is triggered ok displaying the correct variable but I can't update that TileLayer in any way.

```js
export const Map = () => {
    const { colorMode } = useColorMode();

    let state = { center: { lat: 51.505, lng: -0.09 }, zoom: 13 };

    const colorModeUrl = ['https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', 'https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/alidade_smooth_dark/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png']
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log(colorMode);
    }, [colorMode]);

    return (
        <MapContainer
            center={state.center}
            zoom={state.zoom}
            style={{ height: '100%' }}>
            <TileLayer url={colorMode === 'light' ? colorModeUrl[0] : colorModeUrl[1]} />
        </MapContainer>
    )
}
```

Comment: Have you tried: `{ colorMode === 'light' ? <TileLayer url={colorModeUrl[0] /> : <TileLayer url={colorModeUrl[1] />` ? If I'm reading the source code correctly it looks like `TileLayer` will only update the `zIndex` or `opacity` props and needs a full re-render to pick up a new tile url https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/85d68d114d6080ff8d292fc866cae01e2780cdfd/packages/core/src/grid-layer.ts#L3

Comment: Seems to work just updating the url here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-forked-1534x

Comment: Tried that @teddybeard, does not work, even though the component gets re-rendered with the correct url it does not update visually.

For the codesandbox idea, it isn't compatible with the colorMode hook provided by chakra and the workaround on their github issues looks dirty

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the [TileLayer documentation](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-components/#tilelayer), the `url` prop is not mutable. After the initial render the component will not update if the prop is changed:

[image: TileLayer props]

However, you can add a `ref` to the layer and update the url that way

```
export const Map = () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const state = { center: { lat: 51.505, lng: -0.09 }, zoom: 13 };
  const { colorMode } = useColorMode();

  const light = "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
  const dark =
 "https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/alidade_smooth_dark/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png";

  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current.setUrl(colorMode === "light" ? light : dark);
    }
  }, [colorMode]);

  return (
    <div>
      <MapContainer
        center={state.center}
        zoom={state.zoom}
        style={{ height: "100%" }}
      >
        <TileLayer ref={ref} url={colorMode === "light" ? light : dark} />
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-forked-1534x?file=/src/index.js:0-1158

Comment: God bless you, sir!

Answer (score 5):

I encountered a similar issue today trying to change the TileLayer using react-leaflet v4. As mentioned in the accepted answer, the immutability of the TileLayer url attribute is the problem. My dead-simple workaround was to pass a "key" attribute to TileLayer that will change whenever a new tile source is commanded. This will force a remount of the TileLayer component.

Hopefully this isn't subtly dangerous or an antipattern, but it seems to work  with minimal complexity.

Comment: simple and efficient ! Thx